# How to access dynamic data in primeNg dynamic dialog

Tags: angular6, primeng

I am using dynamic dialog of primeNg, I have to pass 2 variable from the component A into the component B which I am opening from A dynamically:

```js
showSkillDetailModal(categoryId: number, skillId: number) {
    const ref = this.dialogService.open(SkillDetailsComponent, {
        width: '70%',
        data: {
            categoryId: categoryId,
            skillId: skillId 
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code for opening the dynamic dialog `SkillDetailsComponent` and the data I am sending is in data array -> `categoryId & skillId`

```js
constructor(
    public ref: DynamicDialogRef,
    public config: DynamicDialogConfig,
    private selfService: SelfDataService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.selfService.getMySkillList(categoryId, skillId).subscribe(response => {
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

But I am not able to get these two variables in `SkillDetailsComponent`. Any idea on how to step forward in this?

Answer (score 3):

Can be accessed like this:

```js
this.config.data.categoryId, this.config.data.skillId
```

Answer (score 1):

Data, which you provide in `DynamicDialog`, can be accessed by injecting `DynamicDialogConfig` in component, which you open through the `DynamicDialog`:

```js
constructor(public config: DynamicDialogConfig) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.config.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**in component A:**

```
showSkillDetailModal(categoryId: number, skillId: number) {
 const ref = this.dialogService.open(SkillDetailsComponent, {
  width: '70%',
  data: {
    categoryId: categoryId,
    skillId: skillId 
  }
});
```

}

**in component B:**

```
constructor(
public ref: DynamicDialogRef,
public config: DynamicDialogConfig,
private selfService: SelfDataService
) {}

categoryId:number;
skillId:number;
ngOnInit() {
  this.categoryId = this.config.data.categoryId;
  this.skillId = this.config.data.skillId
  this.selfService.getMySkillList(
  this.categoryId,this.skillId).subscribe(response => {},error => {                             
   console.log(error);
  })
}
```